# Hyperledger Fabric - collections_config.json is not respecting private data collection

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

```
[
{
  "name": "id1CollectionMarbles",
  "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member', 'Org3MSP.member', 'Org4MSP.member')",
  "requiredPeerCount": 0,
  "maxPeerCount": 3,
  "blockToLive":1000000,
  "memberOnlyRead": true
},
{
  "name": "id1CollectionMarblesPrivateDetails",
  "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member')",
  "requiredPeerCount": 0,
  "maxPeerCount": 3,
  "blockToLive":3,
  "memberOnlyRead": true
},
{
    "name": "id2CollectionMarbles",
    "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member', 'Org3MSP.member', 'Org4MSP.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 0,
    "maxPeerCount": 3,
    "blockToLive":1000000,
    "memberOnlyRead": true
 },
  {
    "name": "id2CollectionMarblesPrivateDetails",
    "policy": "OR('Org3MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 0,
    "maxPeerCount": 3,
    "blockToLive":3,
    "memberOnlyRead": true
  },
  {
    "name": "id3CollectionMarbles",
    "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member', 'Org3MSP.member', 'Org4MSP.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 0,
    "maxPeerCount": 3,
    "blockToLive":1000000,
    "memberOnlyRead": true
 },
  {
    "name": "id3CollectionMarblesPrivateDetails",
    "policy": "OR('Org3MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member', 'Org4MSP.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 0,
    "maxPeerCount": 3,
    "blockToLive":3,
    "memberOnlyRead": true
}
]
```

This is the collections_config.json I am using during chaincode instantiation. But when I query "id1CollectionMarblesPrivateDetails" from Org3 or 4 cli the data from this collection shows up. But it shouldn't.

Please advise if any more details is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do have a separate struct to display the data from this collection right?

Comment: Yeah. I just got it working without any issues. Deleted old chaincode containers and now works like a charm. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: No problem glad it worked out in the end !